# How to use npm package built from a sub folder of a forked repo

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, git-fork

I have forked a project  from github (RocketChat) which have this dependency (package.json):

```
    "dependencies": {
     .................
    "@rocket.chat/fuselage": "0.32.0",
    ..............
```

As business required, I have to make several changes in @rocket.chat/fuselage, which is a package built from a sub folder of another github repo (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Fuselage/tree/develop/packages/fuselage)

Note: @rocket.chat/fuselage is a part of the monorepo above, built by "**yarn build**" at root folder into **root/packages/fuselage/dist**.

So I have forked Rocket.Chat.Fuselage as well. But I have been struggling for days to make my forked Rocketchat point to the customized @rocket.chat/fuselage. We need to make something like:

```
    "dependencies": {
     .................
    "@rocket.chat/fuselage": "0.32.0-ourCompanyName",
    ..............
```

and  build "@rocket.chat/fuselage": "0.32.0-ourCompanyName" only once to be used by other team members (including production). If not possible, building it on each dev machine and prod is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :We decided to use "npm pack"

Step 1: go to fuselage , build it then run

```
npm pack
```

which will generate a tgz file

Step 2: go back to main project. Run

```
npm install "pathTotgzFileInstep1"
```

this will also update dependencies in package.json file

Solution 2: change the package name, create an npm account and publish it to npm registry.
More complicated than solution 1 at first but work better in longterm